# Remote Desktop Admin Disabled after Terminal Services Enabled

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, terminal-server

I have a windows 2003 standard server that we've always used the Remote Desktop Admin (max 2 sessions).  Yesterday, I enabled terminal services on the server, to look into expanding that max sessions.

After enabling it, I an no longer access the Remote Desktop Admin.  It tells me:

```
The remote session was disconnected because there are no Remote Desktop License Servers available to provide a license.
```

Shouldn't I still get my 2 sessions for Remote admin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to connect if you pass the `/admin` switch to the remote destop client.

Comment: This worked.  Is there any other way to get around this, or is this it?

Comment: Install liceneses?  There may be other ways, this is the way I know.